# MSBuild properties: What's the difference between EnableDynamicLoading and CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies?

Tags: c#, plugins, msbuild

I am working on a C# application with plugins feature, and found these two MSBuild properties:

[EnableDynamicLoading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enabledynamicloading) and [CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#copylocallockfileassemblies)

They both seem can copy dependency DLLs to the output folder and I tried both of them worked... so what's the difference?

Comment: I agree that the documentation doesn't really explain. I looked at the files distributed with dotnet. It appears that `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` enables copying dependencies. `EnableDynamicLoading` does more things (i.e. generate a .runtimeconfig.json file and sets `RollForward`) and the value of `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` is changed based on the value of `EnableDynamicLoading`.

Comment: So you mean I just need use `EnableDynamicLoading` right?